# PySpark groupBy count fails with show method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with my `df`, running *Spark 2.1.0*, that has several string columns created as an SQL query from a Hive DB that gives this `.summary()`:

`DataFrame[summary: string, visitorid: string, eventtype: string, ..., target: string]`.

If I only run `df.groupBy("eventtype").count()`, it works and I get `DataFrame[eventtype: string, count: bigint]`

When running with show `df.groupBy('eventtype').count().show()`, I keep getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9040214714346906648.py", line 267, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-9040214714346906648.py", line 265, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 318, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4636.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 633.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 633.0 (TID 19944, ip-172-31-28-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 440): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have no clue what is wrong with the show method (neither of the other columns works either, not event column `target` which I created). The admin of the cluster could not help me either.

Many thanks for any pointers

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Zeppelin. Does `z.show(df.groupBy('eventtype').count())` work?

Comment: yes, I'm using zeppelin - interesting idea!. It throws a slightly different error ..`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext.showDF.
: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`  Should I edit my Q and add the whole error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem, currently we know the issue if your DataFrame contain some limit. If yes, you probably went into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18528

That means, you must upgrade Spark version to 2.1.1 or you can use `repartition` as a workaround to avoid this problem

As @AssafMendelson said, the count() only creates new DataFrame, but it doesn't start calculation. Performing show or i.e. head will start the calculation.

If the Jira ticket and upgrade don't help you, please post logs of workers

Comment: Hi, thanks! I wasn't using .limit, there are only 2 classes, neither I specified any limit in the DF (what is it anyway?).  But your link solved it as I tried to use repartition. `df.repartition('eventtype').groupBy('eventtype').count().show()` works OK! IF you want to add it in your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JanSila Ok I mentioned this :)

Comment: Its a bit funny though. Spent a day on this, could find it in no documentation or tutorial. Why does it happen even when I don't use limit?

Comment: It's hard to say, it would be good if you post issue on Spark Jira with some reproducible example. Maybe not only Limit causes this problem

Comment: Is it maybe if I just pull the DF, do I need to somehow partition it? I did not specify anything like that and not sure where to look for it. In the underlying Hive, the dataset is primarily partitioned by a column I did not include in my subsample

Comment: Basically one needs to repartition the DF by any column and then it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
df.groupBy("eventtype").count()
```

You are actually defining a lazy transformation on HOW to calculate the result. This would return a new dataframe almost immediately regardless of the data size. When you call show you are performing an action, this is when the actual calculation begins.

If you look at the bottom of your error log:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 633.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 633.0 (TID 19944, ip-172-31-28-173.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 440): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You can see that one of the task failed due to a null pointer exception. I would go and check the definition of df to see what happened before (maybe even see if simply doing df.count() causes the exception).

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, when I run `df.count()`, it shows 100k,which is the number of rows I queried. So that's correct.